# A fast way to change your PHP code to be resistan to mysql injection

Tags: mysql, database, code-injection

My question is, how to using a script or other automatic method, change every

$_POST['*'] variables, in all PHP files, to

equivalents resistant to MySQL injection.

I found nothing at google at this topic.

This topic may be useful : [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Quote from the first sentence of the link you put: `Use prepared statements and parameterized queries.`

Comment: also mentioned was mysql_real_escape_string()

Comment: So please just answer, how to increase safety, by changing all POST queries to a little more safe version.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do this reliably. This is exactly what the PHP developers aimed to do with the ill-fated magic quotes feature, but it simply cannot work for everyone everywhere.

**Security is not something you can bolt on an application after it's written; you have to design for it.** In this case, it means that you need to revisit each and every SQL query and rewrite it in a secure manner.

Answer (score 1):

**As Jon already said, each and every SQL query should be reviewed in your application.**

However to answer your question with a possible (crappy) solution you could try this, given you are using Apache..

1. setup apache and `php.ini` to allow setting `auto_prepend_file` via `.htaccess` files
2. write `php_value auto_prepend_file mysql_magic_quote.inc.php` into you `.htaccess`
3. put some code like this in `mysql_magic_quote.inc.php`

Example:

```
foreach($_POST as &$var)
    $var = addquotes($var);
foreach($_GET as &$var)
    $var = addquotes($var);
foreach($_COOKIE as &$var)
    $var = addquotes($var);
foreach($_REQUEST as &$var)
    $var = addquotes($var);
```

**Please note:**

1. this basically simulates the deprecated setting `magic_quotes_gpc`, which **has been deprecated for a reason!**
2. It is just a stupid example - it will definitely **cause side effects**!
3. **Don't do this, review your code instead!**
4. I did not use `mysql_real_escape_string()` here, because that would need an open database connection.
5. I did not use `mysql_escape_string()` here, because that is deprecated as well.

> An example use of addslashes() is when you're entering data into a
>   database. For example, to insert the name O'reilly into a database,
>   you will need to escape it. It's highly recommended to use DBMS
>   specific escape function (e.g. mysqli_real_escape_string() for MySQL
>   or pg_escape_string() for PostgreSQL), but if the DBMS you're using
>   doesn't have an escape function and the DBMS uses \ to escape special
>   chars, you can use this function. This would only be to get the data
>   into the database, the extra \ will not be inserted. Having the PHP
>   directive magic_quotes_sybase set to on will mean ' is instead escaped
>   with another '.
>
> The PHP directive magic_quotes_gpc was on by default before PHP 5.4,
>   and it essentially ran addslashes() on all GET, POST, and COOKIE data.
>   Do not use addslashes() on strings that have already been escaped with
>   magic_quotes_gpc as you'll then do double escaping. The function
>   get_magic_quotes_gpc() may come in handy for checking this.